# Need help fixing a navigation bar, specifically Inline-Block

Tags: html, css

I cannot get the list elements to go where I want them:

I want the first list `$row[1]` to be placed in the middle and the Logout list item to be in the right corner.  And I know someone will yell at me for using the universal character (*) but all my fonts will be the same so it doesn't matter.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Verdana", Sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  /*Change as needed*/
  right: 0;
}

li {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<header>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3>
            <?=$row[1]?>
          </h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Bootstrap you don't need to add external css for trivial adjustments you can use

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"></div>
```

So, You should add the adjustments to the `<li>` tag

```
    <div id="nav"> 
<ul> 
<li  class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"><a href=""><h3 ><?=$row[1]?></h3></a></li> 
<li class= pull-right><a href=""><h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</h3></a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Sorry for bad formatting, done on mobile

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle this. While keeping your styles you could add

```
li:first-of-type {
  width: 100%; 
}

li:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

You may have to adjust on mobile.